# Why does MariaDB execution time is doubled for the same query (LOAD DATA INFILE)?

Tags: mariadb, time, load, execution

I observed a strange behaviour regarding the execution time of a query to import a CSV file in an empty table created beforehand. The query execution time to import the file increases while repeating the import.

I meet this behaviour while importing 10 times the same medium CSV file (0.6 GB, 6 columns, 8 million rows) using TRUNCATE then LOAD DATA INFILE, repeated 10 times within one MariaDB connection.
On the first iteration, the CSV import takes 40 seconds, then about 50 seconds on the second iteration, and from the third to the 10th iteration, the execution time reaches a plateau at 85 +/- 5 s.

I performed the test twice :

- on the mariadb shell (alias "mysql" on GNU Linux)
- on python3 using mysql.connector

And I get the same result, i.e. an execution time that doubles (see figure)...

[image: Execution time vs iteration. An empty table is created, then we repeat 10 time the following : a CSV file is imported and emptied using the TRUNCATE statement. Only the import time is considered here (LOAD DATA INFILE...).]

**• What could explain (or avoid) the execution time being doubled between the first and the third iteration ?**

Steps to reproduce the behaviour :

1. Initiation : create (just once) the empty table with a generated primary key (idRow) :

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `myTable` (`col1` VARCHAR(14), `col2` VARCHAR(14), `col3` VARCHAR(10), `col4` VARCHAR(5), `col5` VARCHAR(5), `col6` VARCHAR(19), `idRow` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`idRow`));
   ```
2. Repeat steps A. and B. 10 times and collect the execution time of step B. for each iteration :

A. Empty the table using TRUNCATE :

```
TRUNCATE TABLE myTable;
```

B. Then import a 0.6 GB-large CSV file of 8 million rows and 6 columns :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/myData/myFile.csv" INTO TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" IGNORE 1 ROWS (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) SET idRow=NULL;
```

Any help to understand this phenomenon would be welcome, dont hesitate to ask for more info.

*Why do I do this ?
The goal is to build a procedure to measure robustly the statistics of the execution time of any query, and how much it fluctuates determines the number of iterations one needs to get a relevant sample size. I was surprised that any query could fluctuate of 100% in execution time.*

Giorgio

MariaDB server :

- OS : Linux Mint 20
- mariadb version : 10.3.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1-log
- innodb version : 10.3.38

[update] I made other interesting observations :

(i) : On the same OS session (i.e. no reboot) : closing the mariadb connection, or restarting the mariadb service (systemctl restart mariadb) does not prevent the 2nd iteration getting slower (50 to 87 s) than the first.

(ii) : After rebooting the OS, the B query gets fast again (40 sec).

Comment: I will now try to monitor whether something obvious is happening on the OS resource usage between 2 successive iterations (to begin with, using top). If you know a handy way to monitor the "right" I/O activity on the disk, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any time between steps A and B?

`TRUNCATE` is effectively `DROP` + `CREATE`.  `DROP` promptly disposes of the table, but there is effort in the background to return the 0.6GB to the OS, etc.  This is probably the problem.

Since you are not likely to be doing `TRUNCATE`+`LOAD` repeatedly, I do not consider this to be a "bug", but rather a side effect of various optimizations.

Comment: Hello Rick, thanks for your anwser. 

"Is there any time between steps A and B ?"
    -> No, nothing is done between steps A. and B. The execution times plotted only accounts for the query B. 
    
By the way, I measured the execution time of the truncate query (on the mariadb shell test), it takes less than 1 seconds and is thus unlikely to explain the execution time being doubled for step B. 

See raw values below for the step A (on mariadb shell) : 
0,102 sec
0,094 sec
0,104 sec
0,205 sec
0,344 sec
0,228 sec
0,107 sec
0,426 sec
0,121 sec
0,170 sec

Comment: My point is that a lot of I/O goes on _after_ the `TRUNCATE` is finished.  It goes on after the background, interfering with everything else (namely `B`).

Comment: Do you mean that _after_ the `TRUNCATE` statement returned OK, the mariadb daemon hasn't really finished yet emptying the table ? Any idea of what is done in background by mariadb after the `TRUNCATE` returned OK ?

Comment: Yes, sort of.  Much of the background activity is in the OS, not the mariadb daemon itself.